# Erlang Netconf Support

Tags: erlang, ietf-netconf

Does Erlang/OTP has Netconf client and server implementation?

Google brings me to http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct_netconfc.html; what is this ct for?

The other project that I found seems to be not maintained https://github.com/FlowForwarding/enetconf

Is there anyone who is using Netconf with Erlang and can help provide some starting point.

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ct_netconf module is part of the "Common Test" test framework, and is probably not usable as a standalone client.

But yes, there is Erlang software that implements Netconf. ConfD was written in Erlang, by the company Tail-F (who got bought by Cisco some years ago). I can't find any online docs, but from mailing list discussions it looks like the free (but not open source) ConfD Basic has Erlang and C bindings. You can get it from here: http://www.tail-f.com/confd-basic/ (registration required).

See http://www.tail-f.com/company-story/ for more background.

(At https://github.com/tail-f-systems there is a Netconf client in Java, but no open source Erlang code.)

Comment: Thanks, @RichardC. Could you, please, explain what are the Commom test frameworks? I also asked a question on the [ct_netconfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660902/ct-netconfcopen-1-raises-an-exception-error-bad-argument): I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @ArielOtilibili See http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/index.html - it's part of the standard distribution.

Comment: What is meant by "is probably not usable as a standalone client"?

Comment: Since it's only shipped as part of the test framework, it might or might not be runnable outside the context of Common Test, and if it is, it probably won't do everything you'd want a generic Netconf client to do. But your mileage may vary - you can always try it.

Comment: Hi Richard & Greg,

I am also looking for a Netconf client. Unfortunately, the available clients such as enetconf are not complete & have not been maintained for the last many years. 

ct_netconfc is complete but works only in the context of CT. It contains both Netconf protocol aspects (such as encoding, decoding, framing, etc as per Netconf RFCs) & CT aspects. We can develop a full-fledged Netconf client by extracting the protocol aspect from ct_netconfc. Do you have suggestions on simplifying this extraction? or do you suggest some other means to develop a Netconf client?

Comment: The CT modules are available for other protocols such as SNMP, SSH, and FTP. The extraction process would be similar in nature if someone has attempted to develop an SNMP/SSH/FTP client using the available CT module. What is your opinion?

  [1]: https://github.com/FlowForwarding/enetconf